# (java string concatenation)How come this is giving this exception?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

this is my simple code.

```
class atmPin{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println("hi there"+x);
    }
}
```

When i run it i get this exception errors.

```
 java atmPin 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
        at atmPin.main(atmPin.java:6)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

is this something to do with java version? i have no idea why is it happening. this is such a simple thing. :(
getting the same kind of exception even with strings.
eg.

```
 String x = "";
     x += "a";
```

Comment: How are you compiling? What source target? How are you running? Same version? Same platform? No bytecode manipulation?

Comment: The class [`java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html) is new in Java 9.

Comment: What happens if you try this at the command prompt javac atmPin.java then java atmPin? When I do so I get "hi there0".

Comment: i think @rgettman is right. i has something to do with java 9. But what's the solution now?

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory` is a class which appeared in Java 9 in order to implement [JEP 280 (Indify String Concatenation)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280) which changes behaviour of `javac` compiler so that it uses `invokedynamic` instructon together with the given class for string concatentaion. So the reason for this error most probably is compiling using `javac` from JDK 9 or later while running this code under Java 8 or less (or, with much less chance, using custom java runtime).

In order to solve it another version of compiler might be used or another version may be specified to the compiler or another JRE should be used for running the compiled class(es).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue with codebase compiled for Java 11. Trial and error led me to discover that a method recursed infinitely before throwing an exception (which was caught and a nice text was concatenated to report it). Apparently `StringConcatFactory` could not work in this situation; as a quick check, explicitly using `StringBuilder` did work, roughly like this:

```
...} catch (Exception e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
                .append("Got some problem: ")
                .append(e.getMessage());
    System.err.println(sb.toString());
    //System.err.println("Got some problem: " + e.getMessage()); // fails
}
```

Although in this case of course the proper solution was to break the infinite loop.

I suppose the factory failed to work because the loop ate all resources on the heap, or something of the sort.